# Thinking Sphinx Delta Index not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, delta-index

I have added the delta column to my table:

```
class AddDeltaIndexToCimgs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cimgs, :delta, :boolean, default: true, null: false
  end
end
```

I migrated

I also added the define_index:

```
define_index do
  indexes search_cache
  has :approved
  set_property delta: true
end
```

And I ran the rake tasks

```
rake ts:stop
rake ts:index
rake ts:start
```

Or `rake ts:rebuild`

Then I add a new record to the table, search for it... and nothing.
The core-indexed records can be found perfectly, but the delta is not working at all.

To search them I use the following:

```
Cimg.search query, with: {approved: true}
```

And yes, every Cimg is approved, and have a bunch of stuff in search_cache, and the new ones are marked with delta=1 in the database. I double checked.

I checked the db/sphinx folder and a lot of files with the name `cimg_delta` are created.

Here is the generated configuration file: http://pastebin.com/z0fHr43k

```
Sphinx version: 2.0.7
Thinking Sphinx gem version: 2.0.5
Rails version: 3.1.0.rc8
Ruby version: 1.9.2p290
```

Any idea of why this may be happening?

Comment: Are you hosting with passenger?

Answer (score 0):

Just a sanity check but in your config/sphinx.yml file
are you doing

```
    development:      
      min_prefix_len: 2  

      indexed_models:
        - Article
        - Match
        - Player
        - Team
        - Group
        - Tournament
        - Ground
        - User
```

Make sure you have added any new indexed models otherwise thinking sphinx will only index the ones specified under each environment. I just added a define_index to User model and couldn't figure out why it wasnt being indexed when running `rake ts:rebuild` I had forgotten to add the indexed_models: user to shinx.yml

Hope this is helpful, Thanks Dave